# show() from matplotlib.pyplot is not working, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to make a plot of an equation for a homework problem. I didn't write the code, just copied and pasted it. Shown below is the code. Does anyone know why the plot is not showing/how to fix it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import *
from numpy import meshgrid


Nmax = 100
Niter = 600
V = zeros((Nmax, Nmax), float)
grid = ones((Nmax, Nmax))
sq3 = sqrt(3.)
y0 = -sq3 / 4.


def contour():
    for j in range(0, Nmax):
        V[0, j] = 1000


for i in range(0, Nmax):
    y = y0 + i * 0.01
    x0 = -0.5
    for j in range(0, Nmax):
        x = x0 + j * 0.01
        if (y <= sq3 * (x + 0.25) and x < 0.) or (y < -sq3 * (x - 0.25) and x >= 0):
            grid[i, j] = 0
        else:
            if y <= sq3 / 4. + 0.01:
                V[i, j] = 0.0
for iter in range(1, Niter):
    if iter % 50 == 0:
        print('On iteration', iter, 'out of', Niter)
    contour()
    for i in range(1, Nmax - 2):
        for j in range(1, Nmax - 2):
            if grid[i, j] == 0.:
                V[i, j] = 0.25 * (V[i + 1, j] + V[i - 1, j] + V[i, j + 1] + V[i, j - 1])
x = range(0, Nmax - 1, 2)
y = range(0, Nmax, 2)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)


def functz(V):
    z = V[X, Y]
    return z


Z = functz(V)
fig = p.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color='r')
ax.set_title('Potential within Triangle (Rotatable)')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Potential')
p.show()
```

I tried using savefig() but when I looked at the file it saved it was just a blank screen

Comment: can you change iter here `for iter in range(1, Niter):` to something else? iter is a built in function in python

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069849/matplotlib-and-axes3d-give-a-blank-picture

Comment: @sadwar yes that did indeed fix my issue! Thanks!!